# How to make custom transition for iOS7 that are compatible with iOS8?

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uikit-transitions

I want to create a custom transition for my view controllers. I have begun to gather some information about the new API introduced in `iOS7`. **But** I have been told that this API somehow changed in `iOS8`. The [video 214 of WWDC 2014](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/214xxq2mdbtmp23/214/214_sd_view_controller_advancements_in_ios_8.mov?dl=1) tackles this point.

**And** some people told me that the custom transitions they created for `iOS7` don't work properly on `iOS8` (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879881/uiviewcontroller-animated-transitioning-fails-in-ios8) and also [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24338700/1670830)).

So my question:

*Could you give some general advice, a guideline, for creating a custom transition that has to be `iOS7` compatible and that will not break on `iOS8`? What should I specifically avoid? What does make the transitions failing to work on `iOS8`?*

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? This is way too broad.

Comment: I am looking for advice from experienced users, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879881/uiviewcontroller-animated-transitioning-fails-in-ios8

Answer (score 0):

Colas, I think that what you need has possibly already been discussed on [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879881/uiviewcontroller-animated-transitioning-fails-in-ios8).

I hope that this is what you need! If you follow the link in the comments below that question it will take you to [This Second Question]["From View Controller" disappears using UIViewControllerContextTransitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338700/from-view-controller-disappears-using-uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning)) where they discuss it more in depth. For example:

> "I played around a bit and it looks like there is an easy workaround,
>   for simple cases. You can just re-add the toViewController's view as a
>   subview of the key window's:
>
> transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
>   UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(toViewController.view)
>   I've checked and the key window's rootViewController is still
>   correctly set, so that's fine. I'm not sure what would happen if you
>   presented your controller from within an already presented modal
>   controller, so for more complex cases, you'll have to experiment
>   around."

I hope that this can help solve your issue as well.